# Is WUBI vulnerable to GOZeus and Cryptolocker etc?

Tags: windows, wubi, malware

The GameoverZeus (P2PZeus) malware, and associated Cryptolocker, has been blocked temporarily, but may resume its potency.  Windows is said to be vulnerable to it, but not Linux.  So is Ubuntu under WUBI safe or not?

Answer (score 0):

Wubi boots Ubuntu. So with regard to viruses there is no difference between Wubi and running a normal dual boot with Ubuntu/Windows. You are not going to get infected while running Ubuntu using Wubi.

Of course if your Windows is already infected then every time you boot Windows there is a risk it encrypts the Wubi root.disk (the virtual disk Wubi uses) or other files required to boot Wubi, in which case you'd no longer be able to boot Ubuntu anymore. This wouldn't happen on a normal dual boot.

The answer is to make sure your Windows is clean. And backup your data.

The last item, backing up your data is a no-brainer that you should do anyway since hardware failure and a malicious virus encrypting your data may have the same net result: you won't have access to your data.